# How to change MSSQL server localhost port

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to change MSSQL server database engine port to 6677 for my local MSSQLSEVER. I have wamp installed on my machine and after installing MSSQL server i am unable to start apache on port 80.
I just want to keep MSSQLSERVER temporary to complete my university project
Thnks

Comment: MS SQL Servers default port is 1433. That shouldn't conflict with port 80

Comment: Did you by any chance also install Skype? Skype for some bizarre reason funks up port 80.

Comment: MSQL doesnt mess with port 80, but IIS can give you problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing SQL Server typically installs the SQL Server Reporting Services service as well, which by default uses port 80.  Go to Windows -> Services and find SQL Server Reporting Services and stop the service (optionally use Properties to set the startup type to none).

You may need to restart the WAMP services after, I forget offhand.